# Trouble Serializing/Deserializing an array list from a text document Java

Tags: java, object, serialization, arraylist, text-files

I need help with reading an array list from a Serialized text file, I do not believe I am having a problem with it however I cannot see if it is actually storing all of the information because I cant print it out to test it, here are the code snipets:
and when I do read from the file I get the ArrayList cannot be cast to StoreAddress

```
   FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Mr Cata\\Desktop\\Testingoutput.txt");
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(ios);
   StoreAddress SAR = (StoreAddress)ois.readObject();
   ArrayList<StoreAddress> ALStore = (ArrayList)ois.readObject();

   for(int i = 0; i < ALStore.size(); i++){
        String list = ALStore.get(i).toString();            
   }

   ios.close();
```

next

```
for(int i = 0; i < ALStore.size(); i++){
   ALStore.get(i);                  
}
```

...

```
for(int i = 0; i < ALStore.size(); i++){
   if (i >= ALStore.size())
   {
        ALStore.add(SA);}
   }

   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Mr Cata\\Desktop\\Testingoutput.txt");
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

   oos.writeObject(ALStore);
   fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing into the file , you write like

```
for(int i = 0; i < ALStore.size(); i++){
  if (i >= ALStore.size()) {
         ALStore.add(SA);
        }
    }
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\MrCata\\Desktop\\Testingoutput.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

oos.writeObject(ALStore);
fos.close();
```

Here you are writing the

> ALStore

which is the array list you are mentioning. But when you are reading, your snippet looks like

```
FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\MrCata\\Desktop\\Testingoutput.txt");
 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(ios);
 StoreAddress SAR = (StoreAddress)ois.readObject();
 ArrayList<StoreAddress> ALStore = (ArrayList)ois.readObject();
 for(int i = 0; i < ALStore.size(); i++){
    String list = ALStore.get(i).toString();

  }

 ios.close();
```

what you have to notice here is you have have written only array list object, but not StoreAddress. If so, what is the need for the line

```
 StoreAddress SAR = (StoreAddress)ois.readObject();
```

in the snippet ? This is the problem here. Remove this and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create a **class with and Instance variable which will an** `ArrayList<Your_Type>.`

**2. Create an object of this class**, and `Serialize the object` and store it in "Myfile.ser" .

**3.** When `De-serializing` , cast the **object to it original type**..

**eg:**

```
          Cat c = (Cat) inputS.readObject();
```

**4.** Now access the ArrayList from this object reference variable.

```
**eg:**

          c.myArr;
```

**You can print the elements of the arraylist using** `for-each` **if you want..like this..**

```
      for (Your_type t : myArr){

             System.out.println(t);

   }
```

Comment: I already have a separate class that serializes, or are you saying make the array list store an array of strings in the serialized class?

Comment: First tell me what does your ArrayList holds.... Second dont Serialize the ArrayList, but Serialize the class that holds this ArrayList as an instance variable

Comment: The serialized class holds a bunch of strings that are received from a GUI through user input.

Comment: Ok..so your are storing a single serialized object with multiple strings, or Mulitple serialized objects with mulitiple strings....?? Whatsoever, store them in an ArrayList and serialize it.. then during deserialization cast it into the Serialized class object type.

Answer (score 0):

In the last code snippet you do a single write of an `ArrayList<ALStore>` however in your first code snippet you try to do two reads, the first one being a `StoreAddress` instance.

Hence the cast exception.

btw, try to adhere to Java convention of writing variables with camel case.